# How to extract data from a text file with python script?

Tags: python

I have i script in python that should search a data file, and copy the relevant data to separate files. Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

os.system("grep \"x \" dynamics.out | awk '{print $2}' > coord.dat")
os.system("grep \"Total\" dynamics.out | awk '{print $4}' > total.dat")
os.system("grep \"Kinetic\" dynamics.out | awk '{print $4}' > kinetic.dat")
```

The problem is that this part that makes the coord.dat file is completely wrong. The output in dynamics.out file is not arranged in such a way that is presumed in this script.
The data file is actually a long series of blocks of data that look like this:

```
    time: 0.2fs
coordinates
C         3.952444338331        0.353499658087        0.155475597879
C         2.898759709487        0.271561183058        2.878962426315
C         0.377507660095        1.575527713456        2.766723501812
N        -0.435656339866        0.616843403256        0.264424997127
C         1.700335308734        1.369156629701       -1.411382740946
C        -2.337147095089       -0.967913098150       -0.045537023463
C        -3.526272967903       -1.434075863003       -2.507321890479
C         1.622297308900        0.380583237194       -4.021983342405
O        -3.540891745414       -1.784144627448        2.005202557948
H         4.590691590007       -1.467822752968       -0.627674161136
H         5.486618188590        1.704246328926        0.014750183919
H         2.660849255805       -1.743362985878        3.501798747714
H         4.277029595067        1.121286334364        4.194254865266
H         0.568970284045        3.642407977900        2.660909012456
H        -1.014510536177        1.242297828699        4.266572018582
H        -3.406669591714        0.378282552422       -3.550366695442
H        -5.529437662690       -2.075200692969       -2.212384192799
H        -2.490387114770       -2.906665564518       -3.579439523150
H         1.675087738572        3.514639806992       -1.458115996333
H        -0.116965875674        1.068581149519       -5.163647181683
H         1.470748269634       -1.655673714451       -4.142927345712
H         3.361564138064        1.115048483423       -4.937771405417
H        -5.134728946067       -2.640023263298        1.567623789643
velocities
        0.000241908669        0.000039611121       -0.000250932377
       -0.000163805243       -0.000115366290       -0.000017375326
       -0.000047784448        0.000248119899       -0.000074616012
        0.000272673498       -0.000017362735        0.000399681421
       -0.000326634443       -0.000254296236        0.000120448584
       -0.000094363714        0.000239927614       -0.000271069374
        0.000122625277        0.000053803004       -0.000088144918
       -0.000112099948       -0.000143815691        0.000140925518
       -0.000020483349       -0.000161160777        0.000050721656
        0.000277228119        0.000550968890       -0.000249788972
        0.000308946542        0.000944826745        0.000083253008
       -0.001453065687        0.000249483273       -0.000194390979
        0.000370071103        0.000328142273       -0.000594811431
        0.000983242907       -0.000247664001       -0.000337676641
        0.000702749595       -0.000531050917       -0.000068247339
       -0.000913913436       -0.000822599342       -0.000519543480
        0.000657300149       -0.001239306947        0.000033192915
        0.000763780031        0.000151892085       -0.000106941733
       -0.000111349513        0.000591872099        0.000360147787
        0.000283007739        0.000537032161        0.000183614425
       -0.001766985000        0.001017499281       -0.000870068723
        0.001560592306       -0.000636221326        0.001124910644
       -0.000596019125        0.001094375746        0.000048984716

Kinetic energy    :        0.030613110934
Electronic energy :      -60.105483063648
Total energy      :      -60.074869952714
Conservation      :       -0.000000051487
self.forces:
       -0.000751933584       -0.004126331042       -0.004033882094
       -0.034302855990        0.029127675777       -0.007001211293
        0.037731564948       -0.009915059812        0.020878531238
       -0.109763802365       -0.102520873021       -0.034608644850
        0.033373305433        0.018949006487       -0.015434320612
        0.078807110369        0.101440274624        0.031960385836
        0.027868883444       -0.012844760956        0.009625682828
        0.011817203866       -0.011548503873        0.038027933611
       -0.016951256413       -0.005848802217       -0.020755575427
        0.002823354740        0.003214778324       -0.005974478408
       -0.012101005124       -0.007850077809        0.000381372379
        0.001958908572       -0.006446492464        0.003077496955
        0.005728700900       -0.005220923285       -0.001710604936
       -0.006358072353       -0.016410380723       -0.003938145281
        0.000121143012        0.012930928986       -0.005592639661
        0.008318475112        0.004530628154        0.009023640965
       -0.010548513939       -0.005006070272        0.008756275583
       -0.000601535778       -0.003075790288       -0.006209965764
       -0.002729816846       -0.003390850759       -0.001421821138
       -0.023967939963        0.000603482820       -0.016983439682
       -0.006731466272        0.010586445711       -0.001984503303
        0.009694983786        0.008555900046        0.002598629870
        0.006564564487        0.004265795793        0.001319282998
state for next step: 1
```

So what I need is from every block of data (there are thousands of them in the file) to get the part that is between the line that says "coordinates" and line that says "velocities". I need to copy that in one file which would have number 23 (No. of atoms) then an empty line, then this data, then again 23, empty line, data, ...

How do I rewrite the script to do this? Or can someone please recommend some literature where I can learn this. I don't know the first thing about Python, but I do have some experience in C and C++ and in Matlab and I understand the basic logic of programming.
Sorry for the long post, but I thought it would be useful to provide a sample of data.
Thank you in advance for any help with this.

Comment: what you're asking is, no offense, fairly straight forward and has been frequently asked here:  it's always a good idea to search stackoverflow and to read the documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+read+text+file  and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+extract+data+file and http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files.  You're going to want to use a list, so this should be helpful too: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

If you need further help/clarifications feel free to edit your question.

Comment: No offense taken :) I know that this is very basic and it should be easy to do, but, as I said I know nothing about Python, and as I looked at other similar questions I couldn't really make the connection to my problem (codewise), although I understand they are very similar in nature. Thank you for the links about Python, I will look at them and try to make some sense myself. :)

Comment: it's okay, I'm struggling through learning C++ right now so I'll just answer your question instead of being a pretentious dick, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
whole_data = []
grab_lines = False
with open('input','r') as atom_file:
    molecule_data = ['23\n\n']
    for line in atom_file:
        if line.startswith('coordinates'):
            grab_lines = True
            continue
        elif line.startswith('velocities'):
            grab_lines = False
            if molecule_data:
                #just checks that we aren't appending an empty list.
                molecule_data.append('\n')
                whole_data.append(molecule_data)
                molecule_data = ['23\n\n']
        if grab_lines: #in python 'is True' is implicit for many types.
            molecule_data.append(line)

with open('output','w') as out_file:
    for molecule in whole_data:
        out_file.write(''.join(molecule))
```

I copy/pasted your input data a few times, so the contents of my `atom_file` look like:

```
    time: 0.2fs
coordinates
C         3.952444338331        0.353499658087        0.155475597879
C         2.898759709487        0.271561183058        2.878962426315
C         0.377507660095        1.575527713456        2.766723501812
N        -0.435656339866        0.616843403256        0.264424997127
C         1.700335308734        1.369156629701       -1.411382740946
C        -2.337147095089       -0.967913098150       -0.045537023463
C        -3.526272967903       -1.434075863003       -2.507321890479
C         1.622297308900        0.380583237194       -4.021983342405
O        -3.540891745414       -1.784144627448        2.005202557948
H         4.590691590007       -1.467822752968       -0.627674161136
H         5.486618188590        1.704246328926        0.014750183919
H         2.660849255805       -1.743362985878        3.501798747714
H         4.277029595067        1.121286334364        4.194254865266
H         0.568970284045        3.642407977900        2.660909012456
H        -1.014510536177        1.242297828699        4.266572018582
H        -3.406669591714        0.378282552422       -3.550366695442
H        -5.529437662690       -2.075200692969       -2.212384192799
H        -2.490387114770       -2.906665564518       -3.579439523150
H         1.675087738572        3.514639806992       -1.458115996333
H        -0.116965875674        1.068581149519       -5.163647181683
H         1.470748269634       -1.655673714451       -4.142927345712
H         3.361564138064        1.115048483423       -4.937771405417
H        -5.134728946067       -2.640023263298        1.567623789643
velocities
        0.000241908669        0.000039611121       -0.000250932377
       -0.000163805243       -0.000115366290       -0.000017375326
       -0.000047784448        0.000248119899       -0.000074616012
        0.000272673498       -0.000017362735        0.000399681421
       -0.000326634443       -0.000254296236        0.000120448584
       -0.000094363714        0.000239927614       -0.000271069374
        0.000122625277        0.000053803004       -0.000088144918
       -0.000112099948       -0.000143815691        0.000140925518
       -0.000020483349       -0.000161160777        0.000050721656
        0.000277228119        0.000550968890       -0.000249788972
        0.000308946542        0.000944826745        0.000083253008
       -0.001453065687        0.000249483273       -0.000194390979
        0.000370071103        0.000328142273       -0.000594811431
        0.000983242907       -0.000247664001       -0.000337676641
        0.000702749595       -0.000531050917       -0.000068247339
       -0.000913913436       -0.000822599342       -0.000519543480
        0.000657300149       -0.001239306947        0.000033192915
        0.000763780031        0.000151892085       -0.000106941733
       -0.000111349513        0.000591872099        0.000360147787
        0.000283007739        0.000537032161        0.000183614425
       -0.001766985000        0.001017499281       -0.000870068723
        0.001560592306       -0.000636221326        0.001124910644
       -0.000596019125        0.001094375746        0.000048984716

Kinetic energy    :        0.030613110934
Electronic energy :      -60.105483063648
Total energy      :      -60.074869952714
Conservation      :       -0.000000051487
self.forces:
       -0.000751933584       -0.004126331042       -0.004033882094
       -0.034302855990        0.029127675777       -0.007001211293
        0.037731564948       -0.009915059812        0.020878531238
       -0.109763802365       -0.102520873021       -0.034608644850
        0.033373305433        0.018949006487       -0.015434320612
        0.078807110369        0.101440274624        0.031960385836
        0.027868883444       -0.012844760956        0.009625682828
        0.011817203866       -0.011548503873        0.038027933611
       -0.016951256413       -0.005848802217       -0.020755575427
        0.002823354740        0.003214778324       -0.005974478408
       -0.012101005124       -0.007850077809        0.000381372379
        0.001958908572       -0.006446492464        0.003077496955
        0.005728700900       -0.005220923285       -0.001710604936
       -0.006358072353       -0.016410380723       -0.003938145281
        0.000121143012        0.012930928986       -0.005592639661
        0.008318475112        0.004530628154        0.009023640965
       -0.010548513939       -0.005006070272        0.008756275583
       -0.000601535778       -0.003075790288       -0.006209965764
       -0.002729816846       -0.003390850759       -0.001421821138
       -0.023967939963        0.000603482820       -0.016983439682
       -0.006731466272        0.010586445711       -0.001984503303
        0.009694983786        0.008555900046        0.002598629870
        0.006564564487        0.004265795793        0.001319282998
state for next step: 1

    time: 0.2fs
coordinates
C         3.952444338331        0.353499658087        0.155475597879
C         2.898759709487        0.271561183058        2.878962426315
C         0.377507660095        1.575527713456        2.766723501812
N        -0.435656339866        0.616843403256        0.264424997127
C         1.700335308734        1.369156629701       -1.411382740946
C        -2.337147095089       -0.967913098150       -0.045537023463
C        -3.526272967903       -1.434075863003       -2.507321890479
C         1.622297308900        0.380583237194       -4.021983342405
O        -3.540891745414       -1.784144627448        2.005202557948
H         4.590691590007       -1.467822752968       -0.627674161136
H         5.486618188590        1.704246328926        0.014750183919
H         2.660849255805       -1.743362985878        3.501798747714
H         4.277029595067        1.121286334364        4.194254865266
H         0.568970284045        3.642407977900        2.660909012456
H        -1.014510536177        1.242297828699        4.266572018582
H        -3.406669591714        0.378282552422       -3.550366695442
H        -5.529437662690       -2.075200692969       -2.212384192799
H        -2.490387114770       -2.906665564518       -3.579439523150
H         1.675087738572        3.514639806992       -1.458115996333
H        -0.116965875674        1.068581149519       -5.163647181683
H         1.470748269634       -1.655673714451       -4.142927345712
H         3.361564138064        1.115048483423       -4.937771405417
H        -5.134728946067       -2.640023263298        1.567623789643
velocities
        0.000241908669        0.000039611121       -0.000250932377
       -0.000163805243       -0.000115366290       -0.000017375326
       -0.000047784448        0.000248119899       -0.000074616012
        0.000272673498       -0.000017362735        0.000399681421
       -0.000326634443       -0.000254296236        0.000120448584
       -0.000094363714        0.000239927614       -0.000271069374
        0.000122625277        0.000053803004       -0.000088144918
       -0.000112099948       -0.000143815691        0.000140925518
       -0.000020483349       -0.000161160777        0.000050721656
        0.000277228119        0.000550968890       -0.000249788972
        0.000308946542        0.000944826745        0.000083253008
       -0.001453065687        0.000249483273       -0.000194390979
        0.000370071103        0.000328142273       -0.000594811431
        0.000983242907       -0.000247664001       -0.000337676641
        0.000702749595       -0.000531050917       -0.000068247339
       -0.000913913436       -0.000822599342       -0.000519543480
        0.000657300149       -0.001239306947        0.000033192915
        0.000763780031        0.000151892085       -0.000106941733
       -0.000111349513        0.000591872099        0.000360147787
        0.000283007739        0.000537032161        0.000183614425
       -0.001766985000        0.001017499281       -0.000870068723
        0.001560592306       -0.000636221326        0.001124910644
       -0.000596019125        0.001094375746        0.000048984716

Kinetic energy    :        0.030613110934
Electronic energy :      -60.105483063648
Total energy      :      -60.074869952714
Conservation      :       -0.000000051487
self.forces:
       -0.000751933584       -0.004126331042       -0.004033882094
       -0.034302855990        0.029127675777       -0.007001211293
        0.037731564948       -0.009915059812        0.020878531238
       -0.109763802365       -0.102520873021       -0.034608644850
        0.033373305433        0.018949006487       -0.015434320612
        0.078807110369        0.101440274624        0.031960385836
        0.027868883444       -0.012844760956        0.009625682828
        0.011817203866       -0.011548503873        0.038027933611
       -0.016951256413       -0.005848802217       -0.020755575427
        0.002823354740        0.003214778324       -0.005974478408
       -0.012101005124       -0.007850077809        0.000381372379
        0.001958908572       -0.006446492464        0.003077496955
        0.005728700900       -0.005220923285       -0.001710604936
       -0.006358072353       -0.016410380723       -0.003938145281
        0.000121143012        0.012930928986       -0.005592639661
        0.008318475112        0.004530628154        0.009023640965
       -0.010548513939       -0.005006070272        0.008756275583
       -0.000601535778       -0.003075790288       -0.006209965764
       -0.002729816846       -0.003390850759       -0.001421821138
       -0.023967939963        0.000603482820       -0.016983439682
       -0.006731466272        0.010586445711       -0.001984503303
        0.009694983786        0.008555900046        0.002598629870
        0.006564564487        0.004265795793        0.001319282998
state for next step: 1

    time: 0.2fs
coordinates
C         3.952444338331        0.353499658087        0.155475597879
C         2.898759709487        0.271561183058        2.878962426315
C         0.377507660095        1.575527713456        2.766723501812
N        -0.435656339866        0.616843403256        0.264424997127
C         1.700335308734        1.369156629701       -1.411382740946
C        -2.337147095089       -0.967913098150       -0.045537023463
C        -3.526272967903       -1.434075863003       -2.507321890479
C         1.622297308900        0.380583237194       -4.021983342405
O        -3.540891745414       -1.784144627448        2.005202557948
H         4.590691590007       -1.467822752968       -0.627674161136
H         5.486618188590        1.704246328926        0.014750183919
H         2.660849255805       -1.743362985878        3.501798747714
H         4.277029595067        1.121286334364        4.194254865266
H         0.568970284045        3.642407977900        2.660909012456
H        -1.014510536177        1.242297828699        4.266572018582
H        -3.406669591714        0.378282552422       -3.550366695442
H        -5.529437662690       -2.075200692969       -2.212384192799
H        -2.490387114770       -2.906665564518       -3.579439523150
H         1.675087738572        3.514639806992       -1.458115996333
H        -0.116965875674        1.068581149519       -5.163647181683
H         1.470748269634       -1.655673714451       -4.142927345712
H         3.361564138064        1.115048483423       -4.937771405417
H        -5.134728946067       -2.640023263298        1.567623789643
velocities
        0.000241908669        0.000039611121       -0.000250932377
       -0.000163805243       -0.000115366290       -0.000017375326
       -0.000047784448        0.000248119899       -0.000074616012
        0.000272673498       -0.000017362735        0.000399681421
       -0.000326634443       -0.000254296236        0.000120448584
       -0.000094363714        0.000239927614       -0.000271069374
        0.000122625277        0.000053803004       -0.000088144918
       -0.000112099948       -0.000143815691        0.000140925518
       -0.000020483349       -0.000161160777        0.000050721656
        0.000277228119        0.000550968890       -0.000249788972
        0.000308946542        0.000944826745        0.000083253008
       -0.001453065687        0.000249483273       -0.000194390979
        0.000370071103        0.000328142273       -0.000594811431
        0.000983242907       -0.000247664001       -0.000337676641
        0.000702749595       -0.000531050917       -0.000068247339
       -0.000913913436       -0.000822599342       -0.000519543480
        0.000657300149       -0.001239306947        0.000033192915
        0.000763780031        0.000151892085       -0.000106941733
       -0.000111349513        0.000591872099        0.000360147787
        0.000283007739        0.000537032161        0.000183614425
       -0.001766985000        0.001017499281       -0.000870068723
        0.001560592306       -0.000636221326        0.001124910644
       -0.000596019125        0.001094375746        0.000048984716

Kinetic energy    :        0.030613110934
Electronic energy :      -60.105483063648
Total energy      :      -60.074869952714
Conservation      :       -0.000000051487
self.forces:
       -0.000751933584       -0.004126331042       -0.004033882094
       -0.034302855990        0.029127675777       -0.007001211293
        0.037731564948       -0.009915059812        0.020878531238
       -0.109763802365       -0.102520873021       -0.034608644850
        0.033373305433        0.018949006487       -0.015434320612
        0.078807110369        0.101440274624        0.031960385836
        0.027868883444       -0.012844760956        0.009625682828
        0.011817203866       -0.011548503873        0.038027933611
       -0.016951256413       -0.005848802217       -0.020755575427
        0.002823354740        0.003214778324       -0.005974478408
       -0.012101005124       -0.007850077809        0.000381372379
        0.001958908572       -0.006446492464        0.003077496955
        0.005728700900       -0.005220923285       -0.001710604936
       -0.006358072353       -0.016410380723       -0.003938145281
        0.000121143012        0.012930928986       -0.005592639661
        0.008318475112        0.004530628154        0.009023640965
       -0.010548513939       -0.005006070272        0.008756275583
       -0.000601535778       -0.003075790288       -0.006209965764
       -0.002729816846       -0.003390850759       -0.001421821138
       -0.023967939963        0.000603482820       -0.016983439682
       -0.006731466272        0.010586445711       -0.001984503303
        0.009694983786        0.008555900046        0.002598629870
        0.006564564487        0.004265795793        0.001319282998
state for next step: 1
```

and the contents of my `out_file` look like:

```
23

C         3.952444338331        0.353499658087        0.155475597879
C         2.898759709487        0.271561183058        2.878962426315
C         0.377507660095        1.575527713456        2.766723501812
N        -0.435656339866        0.616843403256        0.264424997127
C         1.700335308734        1.369156629701       -1.411382740946
C        -2.337147095089       -0.967913098150       -0.045537023463
C        -3.526272967903       -1.434075863003       -2.507321890479
C         1.622297308900        0.380583237194       -4.021983342405
O        -3.540891745414       -1.784144627448        2.005202557948
H         4.590691590007       -1.467822752968       -0.627674161136
H         5.486618188590        1.704246328926        0.014750183919
H         2.660849255805       -1.743362985878        3.501798747714
H         4.277029595067        1.121286334364        4.194254865266
H         0.568970284045        3.642407977900        2.660909012456
H        -1.014510536177        1.242297828699        4.266572018582
H        -3.406669591714        0.378282552422       -3.550366695442
H        -5.529437662690       -2.075200692969       -2.212384192799
H        -2.490387114770       -2.906665564518       -3.579439523150
H         1.675087738572        3.514639806992       -1.458115996333
H        -0.116965875674        1.068581149519       -5.163647181683
H         1.470748269634       -1.655673714451       -4.142927345712
H         3.361564138064        1.115048483423       -4.937771405417
H        -5.134728946067       -2.640023263298        1.567623789643

23

C         3.952444338331        0.353499658087        0.155475597879
C         2.898759709487        0.271561183058        2.878962426315
C         0.377507660095        1.575527713456        2.766723501812
N        -0.435656339866        0.616843403256        0.264424997127
C         1.700335308734        1.369156629701       -1.411382740946
C        -2.337147095089       -0.967913098150       -0.045537023463
C        -3.526272967903       -1.434075863003       -2.507321890479
C         1.622297308900        0.380583237194       -4.021983342405
O        -3.540891745414       -1.784144627448        2.005202557948
H         4.590691590007       -1.467822752968       -0.627674161136
H         5.486618188590        1.704246328926        0.014750183919
H         2.660849255805       -1.743362985878        3.501798747714
H         4.277029595067        1.121286334364        4.194254865266
H         0.568970284045        3.642407977900        2.660909012456
H        -1.014510536177        1.242297828699        4.266572018582
H        -3.406669591714        0.378282552422       -3.550366695442
H        -5.529437662690       -2.075200692969       -2.212384192799
H        -2.490387114770       -2.906665564518       -3.579439523150
H         1.675087738572        3.514639806992       -1.458115996333
H        -0.116965875674        1.068581149519       -5.163647181683
H         1.470748269634       -1.655673714451       -4.142927345712
H         3.361564138064        1.115048483423       -4.937771405417
H        -5.134728946067       -2.640023263298        1.567623789643

23

C         3.952444338331        0.353499658087        0.155475597879
C         2.898759709487        0.271561183058        2.878962426315
C         0.377507660095        1.575527713456        2.766723501812
N        -0.435656339866        0.616843403256        0.264424997127
C         1.700335308734        1.369156629701       -1.411382740946
C        -2.337147095089       -0.967913098150       -0.045537023463
C        -3.526272967903       -1.434075863003       -2.507321890479
C         1.622297308900        0.380583237194       -4.021983342405
O        -3.540891745414       -1.784144627448        2.005202557948
H         4.590691590007       -1.467822752968       -0.627674161136
H         5.486618188590        1.704246328926        0.014750183919
H         2.660849255805       -1.743362985878        3.501798747714
H         4.277029595067        1.121286334364        4.194254865266
H         0.568970284045        3.642407977900        2.660909012456
H        -1.014510536177        1.242297828699        4.266572018582
H        -3.406669591714        0.378282552422       -3.550366695442
H        -5.529437662690       -2.075200692969       -2.212384192799
H        -2.490387114770       -2.906665564518       -3.579439523150
H         1.675087738572        3.514639806992       -1.458115996333
H        -0.116965875674        1.068581149519       -5.163647181683
H         1.470748269634       -1.655673714451       -4.142927345712
H         3.361564138064        1.115048483423       -4.937771405417
H        -5.134728946067       -2.640023263298        1.567623789643
```

**edit**: you could replace the `if grab_lines` statement with:

```
if grab_lines: #in python 'is True' is implicit for many types.
    line = [line.split()[0]]+[str(float(element)*.529) for element in line.split()[1:]]+['\n']
    molecule_data.append('\t'.join(line))
```

The middle part of `line` is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  If any of this is really unclear just ask.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. One more thing, how do I multiply all of these numbers (not 23 of course) by 0.529 before writing them in the output?

Comment: I have tried using: _def mult(x): return x*0.529
                 line=map(mult,line(2,3,4))_ since it is remotely the only idea I have of how to do this (I tried to multiply 2nd, 3rd and 4th element of every line with 0.529), but it seem the syntax is wrong.

Comment: I think I understand. You have split the line into segments, you leave the first one (index 0) intact and the others (index 1 to end) multiply. At the end you join the line again and append it to the variable that is going in output. Right?

Comment: hi seth, I have added my answer for the extracting of contents in the file. Can you please justify why the lines inside `if molecule_data:` are required. I couldn't get it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
grab_lines = False
with open('input','r') as atom_file:
    molecule_data = ['23\n\n']
    for line in atom_file:
        if line.startswith('coordinates'):
            grab_lines = True
            continue
        elif line.startswith('velocities'):
            grab_lines = False
            #if molecule_data:
                #just checks that we aren't appending an empty list.
                #molecule_data.append('\n')
                #whole_data.append(molecule_data)
                #molecule_data = ['23\n\n']
        if grab_lines: #in python 'is True' is implicit for many types.
            new_line = molecule_data.append(line)

with open('output','w') as out_file:
    for molecule in molecule_data:
        out_file.write(molecule)
        #out_file.write(''.join(molecule))
```